# Get Calling stored procedure's name

Tags: find, nested, db2, procedure

IBM DB2 LUW. I have stored procedures calling stored procedures (nesting).  Is it possible in a nested stored procedure (called) to get the name of its parent stored procedure (caller) at run time?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, not with extra programming anyway. If you really need to know the caller name, you could pass it to the callee as an extra parameter.

In recent versions of DB2 there is a special global variable, `ROUTINE_SPECIFIC_NAME`, that contains the specific name of the currently executing routine, so in the caller routine you might call the other SP like so: `CALL SP2(ROUTINE_SPECIFIC_NAME, <other parameters>...)`.